# How to merge 2 multidimensional array's into one

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am new to php and need help on multidimensional arrays. Specifically I want array1 to be the 'value' and array2 to be the 'key'.

Array1:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => 2020-01-02
            [2] => 75
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 50
            [1] => 2020-01-03
            [2] => 35
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200
            [1] => 2020-01-05
            [2] => 165
        )
)
```

Array2:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Price
            [1] => Date
            [2] => PriceNet
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Price
            [1] => Date
            [2] => PriceNet
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Price
            [1] => Date
            [2] => PriceNet
        )
)
```

Desired result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Price] => 100
            [Date] => 2020-01-02
            [PriceNet] => 75
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Price] => 50
            [Date] => 2020-01-03
            [PriceNet] => 35
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Price] => 200
            [Date] => 2020-01-05
            [PriceNet] => 165
        )
)
```

I looked into 'array_merge' and 'array_combine' but I am to new to figure out a smart way to solve the problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You can start with a for/foreach loop.

Comment: Seems like array2 is unnecessary a 2D array: all rows repeat the same information...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44061413/2943403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the power of [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`array_combine`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
$array3 = array_map("array_combine", $array2, $array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Written very fast and not tested well ;) Does it satisfy you?

Of course this code is a little bit hard coded ;)

```
<?php

$array1 = Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            0 => 100,
            1 => '2020-01-02',
            2 => 75
        ),

    1 => Array
        (
            0 => 50,
            1 => '2020-01-03',
            2 => 35
        ),

    2 => Array
        (
            0 => 200,
            1 => '2020-01-05',
            2 => 165,
        )
);



$array2 = Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            0 => 'Price',
            1 => 'Date',
            2 => 'PriceNet'
        ),

    1 => Array
        (
            0 => 'Price',
            1 => 'Date',
            2 => 'PriceNet'
        ),

    2 => Array
        (
            0 => 'Price',
            1 => 'Date',
            2 => 'PriceNet'
        )
        );

$array3 = [];

foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $array3[$key] = [
        $array2[$key][0] => $array1[$key][0],
        $array2[$key][1] => $array1[$key][1],
        $array2[$key][2] => $array1[$key][2],
    ];
}

print_r($array3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach or maybe for loop. But I have implemented a solution for you using the foreach loop.

```
$arr1 = [
            [100, '2020-01-02', 75],
            [50, '2020-01-03', 35],
            [100, '2020-01-05', 165],
        ];
        $arr2 = [
            ['price', 'date', 'priceNet'],
            ['price', 'date', 'priceNet'],
            ['price', 'date', 'priceNet'],
        ];
        $finalResult = [];
        $columns = reset($arr2);
        foreach ($arr1 as $values) {
            $result = [];
            foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
                $result[$columns[$key]] = $value;
            }
            $finalResult [] = $result;
        }
        print_r($finalResult);
```

Here is what output looks like:

[image]

Comment: Gotta say, the other answer seems more elegant